# Awk: In search for better ways of filtering through date columns

Tags: date, awk

I have the following file called dates.csv

```
1,2020-01-27,mom,walk1
2,2023-07-27,dad,walk2
3,2020-06-04,uncle jeff,walk2
4,2022-04-26,uncle celso,walk3
5,2020-01-06,mom,walk2
6,2023-01-19,val,walk1
7,2019-12-02,otice,walk2
8,2021-01-20,uncle celso,walk1
9,2021-04-16,dad,walk3
10,2023-10-03,dad,walk2
11,2021-04-16,uncle jeff,walk3
12,2019-10-11,uncle jeff,walk3
13,2023-01-04,dad,walk3
14,2019-08-22,uncle celso,walk2
15,2022-04-27,val,walk3
16,2019-04-01,dad,walk1
17,2021-01-27,uncle jeff,walk2
18,2019-12-02,val,walk2
19,2022-04-20,uncle celso,walk2
20,2022-07-04,uncle jeff,walk3
```

I am trying to filter dates in a more sophisticated way than I am doing using awk. What I am currently doing is the following. If I want select dates larger than or equal to 2020-06-04 I will run

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$2 >= 20200604{print $2=gensub(/(....)-(..)-(..)/,"\\1\\2\\3",1)}' dates.txt | \
sed 's/,\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)/,\1-\2-\3/1'
```

which gives

```
2,2023-07-27,dad,walk2
4,2022-04-26,uncle celso,walk3
6,2023-01-19,val,walk1
8,2021-01-20,uncle celso,walk1
9,2021-04-16,dad,walk3
10,2023-10-03,dad,walk2
11,2021-04-16,uncle jeff,walk3
13,2023-01-04,dad,walk3
15,2022-04-27,val,walk3
17,2021-01-27,uncle jeff,walk2
19,2022-04-20,uncle celso,walk2
20,2022-07-04,uncle jeff,walk3
```

If I want to select dates smaller than or equal to 2020-06-04 I will run

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$2 <= 20200604{print $2=gensub(/(....)-(..)-(..)/,"\\1\\2\\3",1)}' dates.txt | \
sed 's/,\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)/,\1-\2-\3/1'
```

which results in

```
1,2020-01-27,mom,walk1
3,2020-06-04,uncle jeff,walk2
5,2020-01-06,mom,walk2
7,2019-12-02,otice,walk2
12,2019-10-11,uncle jeff,walk3
14,2019-08-22,uncle celso,walk2
16,2019-04-01,dad,walk1
18,2019-12-02,val,walk2
```

I have been trying around with mktime(), strftime() but am not able to get anything to work that is better than what I have got. I appreciate any ideas on this in advance.

Comment: As [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format dates, you can just use [lexical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) comparisons. Therefore, `$2>=2020-06-04` should work since that is comparing two strings on lexical ordering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify like this:

```
awk -v date=2020-06-04 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2 >= date' file
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I tried it with date=2020-06-04 which seems to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

> trying around with mktime(), strftime()

Using [`mktime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#index-mktime_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029) gives you number which you then compare, `strftime` *might* be coerced into giving string which will compare in expected way, but that requirement might be not obvious to someone else reading your code, therefore I would advise to stick to `mktime`. Let `dates.csv` contain

```
1,2020-01-27,mom,walk1
2,2023-07-27,dad,walk2
3,2020-06-04,uncle jeff,walk2
4,2022-04-26,uncle celso,walk3
5,2020-01-06,mom,walk2
6,2023-01-19,val,walk1
7,2019-12-02,otice,walk2
8,2021-01-20,uncle celso,walk1
9,2021-04-16,dad,walk3
10,2023-10-03,dad,walk2
11,2021-04-16,uncle jeff,walk3
12,2019-10-11,uncle jeff,walk3
13,2023-01-04,dad,walk3
14,2019-08-22,uncle celso,walk2
15,2022-04-27,val,walk3
16,2019-04-01,dad,walk1
17,2021-01-27,uncle jeff,walk2
18,2019-12-02,val,walk2
19,2022-04-20,uncle celso,walk2
20,2022-07-04,uncle jeff,walk3
```

then

```
awk -v year=2020 -v month=6 -v day=4 'BEGIN{FS=",";cutoff=mktime(sprintf("%04d %02d %02d 00 00 00",year,month,day))}mktime(gensub(/-/," ","g",$2) " 00 00 00")>=cutoff' dates.csv
```

gives output

```
2,2023-07-27,dad,walk2
3,2020-06-04,uncle jeff,walk2
4,2022-04-26,uncle celso,walk3
6,2023-01-19,val,walk1
8,2021-01-20,uncle celso,walk1
9,2021-04-16,dad,walk3
10,2023-10-03,dad,walk2
11,2021-04-16,uncle jeff,walk3
13,2023-01-04,dad,walk3
15,2022-04-27,val,walk3
17,2021-01-27,uncle jeff,walk2
19,2022-04-20,uncle celso,walk2
20,2022-07-04,uncle jeff,walk3
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator is `,`, then compute cutoff value by formatting year month day into string compliant with `mktime` and assuming midnight (`00 00 00`), for each line I transform 2nd field into string compliant with `mktime` and filter lines by taking only these with timestamp greater or equal cutoff.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*